# Получить список пакетов, установленных пользователем

Tags: debian, apt-get

`apt-get` иногда выдаёт сообщение, что некоторые пакеты были установлены автоматически и их можно удалить командой `apt-get autoremove`. Значит, где-то хранится признак, по какой причине был установлен тот или иной пакет.

Как получить список пакетов, установленных по запросу пользователя, без автоматически добавленных по зависимостям, и, если возможно, с датой установки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. с помощью «тёплого лампового» *aptitude*:

   ```
   $ aptitude search -F '%p' '!~M ~i'
   ```
2. с помощью *apt-mark*:

   ```
   $ apt-mark showmanual
   ```

---

дату/время запуска (а также параметры и ещё много другой информции) программы *apt-get* можно найти в файлах `/var/log/apt/*`, программы *aptitude* — в файлах `/var/log/aptitude*`, программы *dpkg* (её ведь можно запустить и вручную для установки пакета из скачанного «вручную» файла) — в файлах `/var/log/dpkg.log*`. что плохо — все эти файлы ротируются и (насколько помню, но стоит это уточнить в настройках *logrotate*) со временем удаляются.

---

доп. информация:

- [поисковые шаблоны aptitude](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04.ru.html)
- [настройка того, как отображаются пакеты в aptitude](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.ru.html#secDisplayFormat)

---

**дополнение** по поводу даты установки. вообще-то она не фиксируется в «базе данных» *dpkg*, но более или менее релевантный результат можно получить, например, по дате последней модификации файлов `/var/lib/dpkg/info/имя-пакета*` (например, `имя-пакета[:архитектура].list`, содержащий список файлов пакета).

при распаковке архивов, содержащихся в файле с пакетом, программа *dpkg* указанные файлы (как минимум) перезаписывает (более точный алгоритм можно узнать в документации *dpkg*, или непосредственно в её исходных кодах).

как-нибудь так:

```
#!/bin/bash

export arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)

dostat() {
  stat --printf="$1\t%y\n" $2
}

apt-mark showmanual | while read p; do
  if [ -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/$p.list ]; then
    dostat $p /var/lib/dpkg/info/$p.list
  elif [ -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/$p:$arch.list ]; then
    dostat $p /var/lib/dpkg/info/$p:$arch.list
  else
    echo $p
  fi
done
```

пример вывода:

```
2vcard  2010-03-25 11:56:42.000000000 +0300
abcde   2013-07-20 20:50:31.000000000 +0400
abiword 2013-07-20 22:48:50.000000000 +0400
abook   2013-07-20 22:48:51.000000000 +0400
acl 2013-07-20 22:46:20.000000000 +0400
acpi    2013-07-20 20:50:34.000000000 +0400
acpid   2013-07-20 20:50:34.000000000 +0400
adduser 2013-07-20 20:48:04.000000000 +0400
alien   2013-07-20 20:50:38.000000000 +0400
alsa-base   2013-07-20 22:45:48.000000000 +0400
```

Comment: просил наоборот не автоматические, но всё равно спасибо

Comment: пардон, это опечатка. данную команду набирал вручную, а не скопировал из эмулятора терминала, где запускал обе команды для выяснения полной идентичности их вывода.

Comment: @sercxjo, ещё раз дополнил ответ.

Comment: aptitude работает на много медленнее apt-mark

Comment: @sercxjo, ничего удивительного: более универсальный инструмент обычно уступает более специализированным.